# Given the Fourier transform pair $h(t) \leftrightarrow H(\omega)$, what is the counterpart of $H(-\omega)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Given that $H(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $h(t)$, what is $H(-\omega)$ the Fourier transform of?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question, but I will guess:

If $H(\omega) = \mathcal{F}[h(t)](\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $h(t)$ then $H(-\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $h(-t)$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
H(-\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt\; g(t) e^{-i(-\omega) t}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt\; g(t) e^{-i\omega (-t)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt'\; g(-t') e^{-i\omega t'}\\
&= \mathcal{F}[h(-t')](\omega)
\end{aligned}
$$

From second to third row I substituted $t' = -t$ in the integral.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right.